# How can I shrink a Drawable to match the width a TextView?

Tags: android, html, image, layout, textview

I'm rendering some HTML with image tags within a `TextView`.  I've tried unsuccessfully to scale the images within the `getDrawable()` code.  The code looks something like this.

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlSource, this, this));
@Override public Drawable getDrawable(String url) {
  Drawable.createFromStream((InputStream) new URL(url).getContent(), null);
}
```

Large images don't scale down to fit the screen width.  Instead I only see the leftmost portion of the image, while the rest of the image is cropped off screen.  How can I shrink the images to fit on the screen?

My layout looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/myId"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fillViewport="true" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/myTextView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="22dp" />
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I did it:

```
@Override public Drawable getDrawable(String url) {
  Drawable drawable = 
     Drawable.createFromStream((InputStream) new URL(url).getContent(), null);
  final float scalingFactor = 
     (float)textView.getMeasuredWidth() / d.getIntrinsicWidth();
  d.setBounds(0, 0, textView.getMeasuredWidth(), 
     (int) (d.getIntrinsicHeight()*scalingFactor));
}
```

However, I've discovered that sometimes this technique fails because the TextView hasn't yet rendered and getIntrinsicWidth returns 0. I don't have a solution yet but if you're using this code, you should check it out yourself with some logging. You should be seeing divide by zero exceptions sometimes...